# Element with `position:fixed` is clipped inside parent with `overflow:hidden` and `will-change:transform`

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-position

A parent div with `overflow:hidden` will hide the content that exceed its size.
As expected, we only see the first 20 px.

```html
    <div style="position: relative;
                overflow: hidden;
                height: 20px">
      <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red"></div>
    </div>
```

To ignore the `overflow:hidden` of a parent div, we can set `position:fixed` on the child.
Now, we can see the full 100x100px.

```html
    <div style="position: relative;
                overflow: hidden;
                height: 20px">
      <div style="position: fixed; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red"></div>
    </div>
```

However, we the parent div has `will-change: transform`, then the `position: fixed` no longer works:

```html
<div style="position: relative;
            height: 20px;
            overflow:hidden;
            will-change: transform">
  <div style="position: fixed; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red"></div>
</div>
```

While I can manually override `will-change: transform` to `will-change: auto !important`, it breaks other stuff down the line. I also cannot change `overflow:hidden`. So is there another way to fix this problem?

This is a minimalistic example of my problem. My full problem involves a dropdown/select that is clipped inside a list item.

Comment: Could you give a bit of info about why you need to use will-change? I don’t understand how you would get a performance problem with a drop down menu. Normally will-change should only be used when you’ve experienced bad performance. And  also, as you have found, it introduces stacking-context changes.

Comment: It's not that I want to use it, but the component library I'm using has `will-change` on ripple effects.